# Multi where condition Put on wso2 integration studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, put, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-micro-integrator

I have SQL Update statement with optional filter (multi where condition ) that i would like to exposed as an
Api
the problem is that I need to put where parameters optional :
for example the user will be able to search by id only or by id and age or by id and age and note

tried using the mediator script

```
<resource methods="PUT" uri-template="modif">
        <inSequence>
            <script language="js"><![CDATA[var queryString = "WHERE ";
var AND =" AND ";
var age = mc.getProperty('query.param.age');
var note = mc.getProperty('query.param.note');
queryString += (age)? " age=" + age+" " + AND : " ";
queryString += (note)? " note=" + note+" " + AND : "";
queryString =queryString.toString();
var n = queryString.lastIndexOf(AND);
mc.setProperty('queryString',queryString.slice(0, n));]]></script>
            <property expression="get-property('queryString')" name="uri.var.queryString" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>{
  "_putmodifstudent": {
    "id" : $id,
    "nom": "$nom",
    "prenom:"$prenom",
    "whereage":$age,
    "wherenote":"$note"
  }
}</format>
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="put" statistics="enable" trace="enable" uri-template="http://ITMTNF3RRJSJ:8290/services/studenttest/modifstudent">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
```

**My sql statement in dataservice**

```
 <sql>UPDATE etudiant SET nom =?, prenom =?, age =?, note =? where id =? and age =? and note =?</sql>
```

Comment: Please do not post images of the source code. Copy the actual reproducible code with proper formatting. Also, add all the information that's needed to understand your issue. (e.g: Error messages, details about product versions, infrastructure details etc.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.